# PHP curl requests with 404, curl request itself works fine

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl request:

```
curl -X PUT \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--header "x-api-token: API_TOKEN" \
--header "x-api-user: API_USER" \
--data '{"connection_id":"533905657015830359"}' \
"https://someserver/origination/numbers/%2B17032638425"
```

that works fine from the command line.  when i try run this with a php script it fails with a 404 in the verbose response.

```
$url = "https://someServer/origination/numbers/%2B17032638425";

$postdata = json_encode(array('connection_id'=>'533905657015830359'));

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata
));
  $headers = ['Content-Type: application/json','Accept: application/json','x-api-user: SOME-USER','x-api-token: SOME-TOKEN'];
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I am doing anything blindingly wrong here with the php request?

Comment: Try replacing `%2B` with `+`.

Comment: Also add `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST =>  "PUT"`

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but it seems to me you are using a PUT request in your shell CURL and a POST request in the PHP version. The two HTTP methods, while quite close in their meaning, are not generally managed in the same way by API endpoints.